# Vimeo upload access for basic users to upload videos to their accounts

Tags: ios, swift, vimeo

I want users to upload their recorded videos to their Vimeo accounts through my app, I've got upload access from Vimeo and it says "Your app has access to upload to your own account" it only lets me upload to my account, do I have permission to upload to basic users' accounts? If not, how can I get this permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requesting upload access for your application, Vimeo can grant you "App Owner" or "All accounts" upload access. In other words, they can grant your application the ability to upload only to your own account, or the ability to let others authenticate with your application and upload to their accounts.

Contact Vimeo and explain your usecase, they'll be able to guide you in the right direction and check your application's upload access permissions.

https://vimeo.com/help/contact